# How to handle duplex wcf in azure wcf relay

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-servicebusrelay

I have a duplex wcf service that works fine but know i want to use the ability of azure wcf-relay to connect the client and the service. I made it all work with all my other services my only problem is the duplex service since it has a callback and i am not sure what should i do, how to implement it with the azure wcf relay.

Example:

```
 [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IViewerManagerCallback), Name = "IViewerManager", Namespace = "http://samples.microsoft.com/ServiceModel/Relay/")]
public interface IViewerManager
{
    [OperationContract]        
    [FaultContract(typeof(OperationFaultData))]
    ViewLayout GetViewLayout(int viewId);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the classes provided in [Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus?view=azureservicebus-4.1.1), we could find that Azure Relay WCF relays only provide 2 types of ws- bindings. WSHttpRelayBinding and WSHttpRelayBinding. I can't find a class which implement the similar feature of WSDualHttpBinding for Azure WCF relays. Maybe it is not support in Azure WCF relays currently. I suggest you submit a feedback on [Azure feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) which is used for posting ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the DuplexChannelFactory to open the  create and open the channel.It helped me with the solution but unfortunately i still have some issues  with delays .

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.